# How to debug a maven reporting plugin source code?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a custom maven reporting plugin source code.

I have tried to run as 'Maven build' with goals-site. But it doesn't stop at my breakpoint in 'executeReport' method of the plugin code.

How do I debug it in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I normally create a seperate "tester" project in Eclipse

And add the plugin i am developing as a dependency in the Pom file e.g.

```
<build>
    .....
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
        <artifactId>yourcustomplugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </plugin>
    ....
</plugins>

</build>
```

In this new project you then right click in Eclipse and do

Debug As->Build...

In here specify your goal in the goal section

Your Breakpoint in your maven plugin project in the workspace should then be hit.

I am assuming you are using [m2eclipse](http://www.sonatype.org/m2eclipse/)

Comment: It is not working ! Since I give this as a jar file in dependency, I can't debug it. Is there any way to attach the source of plugin to the jar specified in the dependency section ?